# Установка якоря на кнопку

Tags: android, list

Есть список `TextView`, в которых при нажатии на `Button` вылетает подсписок. Проблема заключается в том, что если мы находимся на `TextView37`, при нажатии на кнопку нас выкидывает к первому `TextView1`. 
Есть ли параметр или код, который "ставит якорь", то есть оставляет текущую позицию в `TextView`, не перенося нас в начало списка?
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Вот так я получаю №ряда

```
        String idCurrent = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("id"));
        String rowKeyCurrent = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("rowKey"));


        holder.llResults.setTag(R.id.TAG_ID, idCurrent);
        holder.llResults.setTag(R.id.TAG_ROW_KEY, rowKeyCurrent);
```

А вот onClick:

```
            holder.llResults.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                agendaItemClick.onVotesViewClick((String) view.getTag(R.id.TAG_ID), (String) view.getTag(R.id.TAG_ROW_KEY));
            }
        });
```

List:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="12dp">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="20dp"
                  android:background="@drawable/bg_status_transperant" android:id="@+id/llTag"
                  android:visibility="visible" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTag" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Обновленный" android:textSize="14sp"
                  android:textColor="@color/brownish_grey" android:maxLines="2"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Название"
              android:id="@+id/txtName" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="40sp"
              android:layout_marginRight="24dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Кнопка:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="100dp"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
              android:id="@+id/llResults" android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:clickable="true">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="18dp" android:layout_height="18dp" android:id="@+id/imageView20"
               android:src="@drawable/graf_4"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="24dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0" android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Comment: Как вы показываете выпадающий список?

Comment: Элементы располагаются под каждым TextView(первый, второй и т.д.)

Comment: код, который показывает их где?

Comment: у вас скорее всего ошибка в коде, который показывает выпадающие списки

Comment: Не думаю, что по картинкам кто то может догадаться что и почему у вас там происходит и как этому помочь. Без воспроизводимого примера проблемы можно только с уверенностью сказать, что вы что то делаете не так.

Comment: обновил пост. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Где эти TextView находятся - ListView, RecyclerView или что? По добавленному коду все еще нельзя воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: Как это все работает (должно работать) по прежнему остается тайной. Здесь все же ресурс программистов, а не экстрасенсов. По еще добавленному коду все так же нельзя воспроизвести проблему. Попробуйте представить, что вы ничего не знаете о своем проекте и вам показывают этот вопрос - почему не работает? Вы бы смогли на него ответить, имея две строчки кода и какую то разметку?

Comment: Приходит через JSON. Список парсится. Элементов, предположим, 27. Когда я листаю в низ(дохожу до 15) и нажимаю на кнопку(clickable image) разворачивается подсписок данного элемента, но меня выкидывает в начало списка(т.е. к первому элементу). Что Вас конкретно интересует? Использую LinearLayout.
Меня интересует вопрос: есть ли параметр или функция, которая оставляет курсор на кликнутом елементе?

Comment: Что вы листаете? ListView?

Comment: да. В каждом элементе ListView есть кнопка(clickable image).